# How to put regex validation for list of string using Jsonschema2pojo

Tags: java, json, validation, jsonschema2pojo

I want to validate list of string (ccEmailAddresses) in my pojo. I'm using Jsonschema2pojo to create Java pojo from json.

Json  -

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
"title": "Email Recipient",
"description": "Schema for an email recipient document.",
"type": "object",
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": true,
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 30
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 50
    },
    "emailAddress": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "|^[\\w-']+(?:[\\.\\+&=][\\w-']+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$",
        "maxLength": 255,
        "required": true
    },
    "ccEmailAddresses": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
            "type" : "string",
            "pattern": "|^[\\w-']+(?:[\\.\\+&=][\\w-']+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As given above, pattern does not validate ccEmailAddresses. However it does validate emailAddress. So for single element it just works fine but not for list.

Further I tried putting pattern as -

```
{
"$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/schema",
"title": "Email Recipient",
"description": "Schema for an email recipient document.",
"type": "object",
"additionalProperties": false,
"required": true,
"properties": {
    "firstName": {
        "type": "string",
        "maxLength": 30
    },
    "lastName": {
        "type": "string",
        "minLength": 1,
        "maxLength": 50
    },
    "emailAddress": {
        "type": "string",
        "pattern": "|^[\\w-']+(?:[\\.\\+&=][\\w-']+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$",
        "maxLength": 255,
        "required": true
    },
    "ccEmailAddresses": {
        "type": "array",
        "pattern": "|^[\\w-']+(?:[\\.\\+&=][\\w-']+)*@(?:[\\w-]+\\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,10}$",
        "items": {
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

}

Even this doesn't work. I would not prefer moving out from Jsonschema2pojo because of this.
I couldn't find any documentation on this but this must be very common use case.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,